# ¿Cómo funciona el nuevo procedimiento de firma/subida de aplicaciones de Android o cómo aplicar correctamente las versiones de firma?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentado firmar y subir una App a Google Play Store.

La app fue diseñada en Android Studio y estoy siguiendo los procedimientos indicados para firmarla:

- `Build`
- `Generate Signed APK`
- `release` (en el Build type)

A ese punto aparece algo nuevo: dos versiones de firma distintas: `V1` y `V2`, como se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero elegí la `V2`, pues el enlace decía que era una forma más moderna y segura de firmar las app.

Pero al intentar subir el archivo `.apk` generado, me dio el siguiente error:

> #### No se ha podido subir el archivo
>
> Has subido un APK con una firma no
>   válida (más información sobre la firma de aplicaciones). Error de
>   apksigner: `ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures`

Leí en una respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés que había que marcar ambas opciones al momento de generar el APK, lo cual hice... aunque al hacerlo, no cambió en nada el archivo `app-release.apk` (que es el que debo subir desde la consola de Google). O sea, **no se generó un archivo nuevo. Sin embargo, sí se generó a la hora en que hice el segundo build, un archivo `app-debug.apk`.**

Llegado a este punto no sé que debo hacer para subir mi archivo.

¿Debo subir también el `app-debug.apk`? ¿Debo subir otro archivo suplementario puesto que el error dice `No JAR signatures`? ¿Debo hacer algún cambio en el gradle para que me suba el archivo?

La documentación de Google al respecto es a mi juicio muy amplia... dispersa, confusa... En ninguna parte encuentro una simple guía que te diga paso por paso lo que debes hacer.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

en mi caso siempre selecciono ambos tanto el V1  y V2 y sin problemas se sube a playstore,

el **V1** es la versión de tu APK que google analiza en busca de codigo malicioso
el **V2** es la versión que se descarga a los dispositivos en playstore.

**Ambos van empaquetados en un solo APK signed**

[image: V1]

Comment: Yo genero las aplicaciones únicamente con V1, eso quiere decir que ¿entonces no podré subir mi aplicación a playstore?

Comment: efectivamente el V2, incluye el apk firmado, por lo tanto si no esta firmado google lo rechaza

Answer (score 0):

Unas de las dudas que tengo son las siguientes:

- ¿Has subido la aplicación antes?
- ¿Has creado alguna nueva firma?

Según lo que leí, no debería de darte problema, el archivo se debe generar con este nombre "**app-release.apk**" en caso de que se generase con "**app-debug.apk**", procura en comprobar el "**Build Type:**" y seleccionas "**Release**".

[image: Generate Signed APK]

> ¿Debo hacer algún cambio en el gradle para que me suba el archivo?
>   En caso de que no te dejase exportar como **Release** añade esto en el **Build.grandle**

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
```

Lo tienes que añadir dentro de **android {...** espero que te haya resuelto algunas dudas, saludos.